# What does the current perl expression mean

Tags: perl, expression

I've encountered this expression in perl :

```
if($temp !~ /^\.\n$/)
```

I'm not familiar with expressions in perl, and wanted to know what it meant !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/PAT/`, short for `m/PAT/`, is the match operator. It checks if the bound value matches the regex pattern `PAT`.

`=~` is the binding operator. It can be used to specify the value the match operator checks for a match against the regex pattern, so `$temp =~ /PAT/` checks if `$temp` matches the pattern `PAT`.

`EXPR1 !~ EXPR1` is the same as `!(EXPR1 =~ EXPR1)`, so `$temp !~ /PAT/` checks if `$temp` doesn't match the pattern `PAT`.

The pattern in question checks if the value consists of a single character other than newline followed by one or two newlines.

So the expression is true if the value of `$temp` doesn't consist of a single character other than newline followed by one or two newlines.

For example,

- `"a\n"` matches. Body of `if` won't be entered.
- `"a\n\n"` matches (though probably unintentionally). Body of `if` won't be entered.
- `"a"` doesn't match. Body of `if` will be entered.
- `"\n"` doesn't match. Body of `if` will be entered.
- `"\n\n"` doesn't match. Body of `if` will be entered.
- `"ab\n"` doesn't match. Body of `if` will be entered.

Comment: Good to know ! But what does the above expression mean specifically ?

Comment: The body of the `if` will be entered if the value of `$temp` doesn't consist of a single character other than newline followed by one or two newlines.

Comment: My bad.. the dot matches the `a` in this case.. (but it cannot match a newline unless `s` modifier is given..., but your answer captures that case correctly)